# How to remove XML elements dynamically

Tags: xslt

I am basically looking for an XSLT (say a callable template), which will take as input an xml AND an element to be deleted in the XML and give me back the final XML after deleting that particular element in the XML.

Example:

```
<Request>
  <Activity1>XYZ</Activity1>
  <Activity2>ABC</Activity2>
</Request>
```

Now i need an xslt for which i must give the above xml as input and the element to be deleted (Say `<Activity1>`) as input. The XSLT must return the final xml after deleting the element passed to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a modified copy-template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet ...>
   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:variable name="removeNode">Activity1</xsl:variable>

   <xsl:template match="node()">        
     <xsl:if test="not(name()=$removeNode)">
       <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*">        
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How to pass the parameter to yout template depends on your used XSLT-processor.

**Edit**

Another possibility is to ignore the node when needed:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*[not(self::element-to-ignore)]" 
                       mode="renderResult"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="renderResult">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="renderResult"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help . But I am not able to put this in a callable template so that it can be used for the removal of any particular element . Could you help me on this . The callable template must take as input , the XML and the element to be removed and must give back the final xml after deleting that particular element in the XML .

Comment: "Give back" somehow complicated in XSLT. You can save the result of may first template in a variable and then work on this element tree. The second possibility I added allows you remove the elements when needed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic transformation that accepts a global (externally specified) parameter with the name of the element to be deleted:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pDeleteName" select="'c'"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:if test="not(name() = $pDeleteName)">
   <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on any XML document** (for example the following):

```
<a>
 <b>
   <c/>
   <d>
     <e>
       <c>
         <f/>
       </c>
       <g/>
     </e>
   </d>
 </b>
</a>
```

**the correct result is produced -- the source XML document in which any element having name the same as the string in the `pDeleteName` parameter -- is deleted**:

```
<a>
   <b>
      <d>
         <e>
            <g/>
         </e>
      </d>
   </b>
</a>
```

**As can be clearly seen, any occurence of the element `<c>` has been deleted.**

Comment: Hi Dimitre , really appreciate your help .

Comment: @Dravid: I am glad to know my answer was useful. Here at SO the official form of expressing gratitude is by accepting the best answer. This can be done by clicking on the check-mark next to the best answer. Please, consider doing so.